# EJB Creating Calendar-Based Timer Expressions

Tags: timer, ejb, ejb-3.0

I need to create 3 timers.

First timer shall timeout every 3 days but roll over the next month. For example, If I want the timer to trigger every 3 days. So, the timer shall timeout on days of month 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25 ,28. But if this month is 31 days then the timer shall trigger on days 31 then day 3 of the next month, if this month is 30 days it shall trigger on day 1 of the next month, but if this month is just 28 days then it shall trigger on day 3 of the next month.

Second timer shall every 3 weeks on Sunday.

Third timer shall trigger every 6 months on the end of the month.

I'm trying to use Calendar based timer (timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule)) but I couldn't find a way to establish the above timers since the interval x/y is not applicable for months and weeks. And for days it doesn't support roll over next month. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the use of [ScheduledExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjmq5/index.html)? Some other examples [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/schedule-expression/README.html)

If the standard API does not cover you needs then you might need to consider using a more specific library, for example [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Hope that helps.